# How to create whitelisted URL pattern for Google Firebase Dynamic link?

Tags: firebase, redirect, dns, firebase-dynamic-links, whitelist

My Dynamic link giving the error as **Invalid Dynamic Link - Blocked**

We could not match param 'https://www.toppscholars.com?meetingId=546546&pwd=98456' with whitelisted URL patterns in this Google project.

I tried to create whitelist which goes to playstore:

^https://play.google.com/.*id=com.appname$

Unable to use for below URL, need redirection on below url to read the values.
https://www.toppscholars.com?meetingId=546546&pwd=9845

I'm expecting the dynamic link to open my app and read the parameters.
If app not present it will go to app store / playstore.

Expecting the link to work across all the devices and platforms without error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue resolved by below example.

**Link**: https://www.example.com/post?postId=hy48ndmFLMdxydT7mGPq

**Allowlist URL Pattern**: `^https{0,1}:\/\/www\.example\.com\/post([\/#\?].*){0,1}$`

Similarly for

**Link**: https://www.toppscholars.com?meetingId=546546&pwd=9845

**Allowlist URL Pattern**: `^https{0,1}:\/\/www\.toppscholars\.com([\/#\?].*){0,1}$`